# can you add iframe values

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe that basically converts 10 Euro to the price of bitcoin in the live price.
Is there any way i can take the result of the iframe and -9.6%  as im looking for a way to convert euro to bitcoin but also -9.6% from the result.

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: share demo code for understanding code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#MyIFrame").contents().find("#AmazingConversion").val();
```

to get the value of the conversion and then do what ever you want.

This will work on same doomain. So if your iframe is from another domain it's not possible simply because same origin policy.

If you however are doing a userscript/browser plugin. You can include the execution of the script to the website you have that conversion thing and it will bypass the same origin problem.